# How can I elegantly compare instance variables of couple classes without metaprogramming?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I have two instances of different classes. These classes have the same amount of instance variables, and I need to check if these instances of different classes have particular equal instance variables.

These instance variables can be fetched through `attr_reader`.

I found a way to do that, but it's dirty. Is there any way to make it cleaner (without metaprogramming)?

```
[:attr_1, :attr2].all?{ |attr| a.public_send(attr) == b.public_send(attr)) }
```

Comment: And you should probably show a more complete example to avoid further down and close votes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this class:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
  end
end
```

And these two instances:

```
foo = MyClass.new(1, 2, 3)
bar = MyClass.new(1, 2, 3)
```

You can either compare the attributes one by one:

```
foo.a == bar.a && foo.b == bar.b && foo.c == bar.c #=> true
```

Or with the help of an array: (arrays are compared element-wise)

```
[foo.a, foo.b, foo.c] == [bar.a, bar.b, bar.c] #=> true
```

Or you could `extend` the instances with a custom module that exposes the attributes you are interested in:

```
module AttributesMethod
  def attributes
    { a: a, b: b, c: c }
  end
end

foo.extend(AttributesMethod)
bar.extend(AttributesMethod)

foo.attributes #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
bar.attributes #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

This allows you to write:

```
foo.attributes == bar.attributes #=> true
```